# Read nested json in javascript and build HTML table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, nested

I am trying to read Nested Json object using javacript and convert it into HTML table with search option 
 and export the table data into excel sheet, but Unable to read nested objects, can anyone please help with some pseudo code

```
{
 "Person1": {
        "updateddate": "2017-05-10", 
        "desc": "new joinee", 
        "Id": {
            "12345": {
                "locallinks": [
                    "local_link1"
                ]
            }
        }, 
        "externallinks": [
            "external_link1"
        ], 
        "updateduser": "admin"
    } 
    },
    "Person2": {
        "updateddate": "2017-06-10", 
        "desc": "existing", 
        "Id": {
            "12346": {
                "locallinks": [
                    "local_link1"
                ]
            }
        }, 
        "externallinks": [
            "external_link1"
        ], 
        "updateduser": "user"
    } 
    },
    "Person3": {
        "updateddate": "2017-06-10", 
        "desc": "new joinee", 
        "Id": {
            "12347": {
                "locallinks": [
                    "local_link1"
                ]
            }
        }, 
        "externallinks": [
            "external_link1"
        ], 
        "updateduser": "admin"
    } 
    }
    }
```

I need HTML table with Headers

`Person , Updated Date, Desc, ID , external links , Updated User`

Comment: Please add code for what you have tried?

Comment: Also please validate your JSON (Throw a lot of errors). https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: For every `Person` there's an extra closing bracket. BTW, you haven't posted a lick of JavaScript ...

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear but I can figure out what you want. There is a code for giving idea to you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
  <table id="data" border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>Person </td>
        <td>Updated Date</td>
        <td>Desc</td>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>external links</td>
        <td>Updated User</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody></tbody>
  </table>

  <script>
    let xhttp;

    function getData() {
      xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
          const data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
          console.log(data);
          createData(data);
        } else {
          console.log(this.readyState, this.status);
        }
      };

      xhttp.open('GET', 'http://www.mocky.io/v2/5e9c2d9a30000059000a7dc5',
      true);
      xhttp.send();
    }

    getData();

    function createData(data) {
      const table = document.querySelector('#data>tbody');
      const tableRow = document.createElement('tr');

      Object.values(data).forEach(person => {
        tableRow.innerHTML = `
        <td>${'xxx'}</td>
        <td>${person.updateddate}</td>
        <td>${person.desc}</td>
        <td>${person.Id}</td>
        <td>${person.externallinks}</td>
        <td>${person.updateduser}</td>
  `;

        table.appendChild(tableRow);

      });
    }
  </script>
</body>

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `JSON` you have added is not valid. Use the following `JSON` data:

```
var data = 
{
 "Person1": {
        "updateddate": "2017-05-10", 
        "desc": "new joinee", 
        "Id": {
            "12345": {
                "locallinks": [
                    "local_link1"
                ]
            }
        }, 
        "externallinks": [
            "external_link1"
        ], 
        "updateduser": "admin"
    },
    "Person2": {
        "updateddate": "2017-06-10", 
        "desc": "existing", 
        "Id": {
            "12346": {
                "locallinks": [
                    "local_link1"
                ]
            }
        }, 
        "externallinks": [
            "external_link1"
        ], 
        "updateduser": "user"
    },
    "Person3": {
        "updateddate": "2017-06-10", 
        "desc": "new joinee", 
        "Id": {
            "12347": {
                "locallinks": [
                    "local_link1"
                ]
            }
        }, 
        "externallinks": [
            "external_link1"
        ], 
        "updateduser": "admin"
    }
}
```

To read nested Objects you can use `Object.keys` method

```
Object.keys(data).forEach(person =>{
  console.log("person ",person)
  Object.keys(data[person]).forEach(props =>{
    /*Nested JSON props here*/
  })
})
```